# What is the rationale of climate activists pouring soup on Van Gogh paintings of sunflowers?

Tags: citizen-activism

I do not really understand the reasoning behind. Should not it be at least something like *[Arrival of the Normandy Train, Gare Saint-Lazare](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Claude_Monet_-_Arrival_of_the_Normandy_Train,_Gare_Saint-Lazare_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg)* by Monet ? (steam locomotive depicted there at least has large carbon footprint). Why sunflowers? Growing more sunflowers does not harm the climate. What is wrong with promoting how nice they can be?

Comment: Related question: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/76502/environmentalist-attacking-artworks-are-they-trying-to-raise-awareness-or-discr

Comment: Analogous from the 20th century: [A Decade of AIDS Activism Changed America--and ACT-UP](https://www.sfgate.com/news/article/A-Decade-of-AIDS-Activism-Changed-America-and-2849161.php): "September 8, 1989: Activists disrupt opening of San Francisco Opera season."

Comment: @uhoh - It's fairly analogous, insofar as the protesters have thus far only targeted paintings with proper protection, so their actions are indeed only disruptive (and thus positive). But if someone, at some point, misses that trend and actually destroys some old painting, it will not be completely analogous.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Just curious; is there really such a concept as completely vs incompletely analogous scenarios? Is there an objective test one apply to a pair of things to determine how completely one is the analog of the other? We can exclude the identity operator; if one is identical to the other then some may argue that excludes them from being analogous *by definition* right? So how to draw the line between complete and incomplete analogs? Or perhaps analog completeness is in the eye of the beholder - everyone has their own opinion and nobody can say objectively?

Comment: @uhoh - If you want to be *that* specific and point out that no analogy can be perfect, we could speak of "fairly analogous" and "not very analogous."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the painting. The painting is simply high profile enough to make the media engage with the protesters rather than ignore them.

Here is one of the protesters [explaining](https://www.artnews.com/art-news/news/just-stop-oil-protestor-van-gogh-sunflowers-why-video-1234643678/) their actions. Which I found by googling 'why soup on sunflowers' the link provided was the 2nd result.

> “We’re not asking the question, should everyone be throwing soup at paintings?” said Plummer. “What we’re doing is getting the conversation going so we can ask the questions that matter.”

Comment: Did the protestors ask "why are you more upset about the destruction of this painting than about the destruction of the entire human race and planet earth?" or did I read that from someone else?

Comment: Just a minor addition: one of the reasons they picked the paintings they picked is that they are behind glass.

Comment: @JordiVermeulen Have you got a quote to cite for that? Or is it speculation?

Comment: @user253751:  You might have heard [this NPR interview with one of the activists:](https://www.npr.org/2022/11/01/1133041550/the-activist-who-threw-soup-on-a-van-gogh-explains-why-they-did-it) "[I]t's a beautiful work of art and I think a lot of people, when they saw us, had feelings of shock or horror or outrage because they saw something beautiful and valuable and they thought it was being damaged or destroyed. But, you know, where is that emotional response when it's our planet and our people that are being destroyed?"

Comment: It might be worth including this quote from the protestor as well, from the source in your answer: "as a queer woman ... the reason that I’m able to vote, go to university, and hopefully someday marry the person I love is because of people who have taken part in civil resistance before me". An important part of her rationale is that she believes LGBTQ rights, historically, were brought to people's attention by similar protests.

Comment: Was the question of, "won't this just unite people against protestors who they see as vandals" explicitly addressed?

Comment: @LioElbammalf they've made statements to this effect, and have consistently targetted paintings that are protected by glass.

Comment: They have, though, damaged the frames on a number of the installations they've attacked.

Answer (score 25):

I think the accepted answer misses the main point of the protest. [In the protestors' own words](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2022/oct/14/just-stop-oil-activists-throw-soup-at-van-goghs-sunflowers):

> "What is worth more, art or life? Is it worth more than food? More than justice? Are you more concerned about the protection of a painting or the protection of our planet and people?"

People are viscerally shocked when they hear that a priceless artwork may have been destroyed (as stated in the linked article, they carefully chose one protected by glass), but are happy to carry on their everyday lives while we literally destroy the basis for life on Earth. The aim of the protest was to transfer some of that visceral shock to climate breakdown.

Comment: It's perhaps worth remembering this site is for, uh, "meta" discussion of politics, and not politics. "while we literally destroy the basis for life on Earth" is just a scientific prediction.

Comment: Isn't that argument kind of unrelated to the ethics of their actions? For a *reductio ad absurdum*, if someone killed a few thousand people to bring attention to climate change, they could ask "Are you more concerned about the deaths of these few thousand people, or the deaths of millions of people due to climate change?'" No one would view that as a *justification*, though.

Comment: There's also a bit of a logical flaw in the notion that because people are more *shocked* at someone throwing soup at a painting, they must be more *concerned* about it. Which do you think shocks people more: seeing soup thrown at a painting, or being told that they will die someday? And which are they generally more concerned about?

Comment: Overall, the fact that no permanent damage was done to the paintings seems like a much stronger argument than those.

Comment: What about the simple fact that this is what gets international headlines? A recurring theme after similar spectacular/disruptive action is some journalist asks protesters "but why not protest peacefully", and the answer gravitates towards "we did, but you weren't there to talk to us then".

Comment: @Obie2.0 You wish it was reduction ad absurdum - that's how some manifesto written by mass shooters become well known. Other thing is whether such publicity was genuinely making people supportive of their ideas...

Comment: @AmiralPatate - Note that this *was* a peaceful protest. It apparently shocked some people (though what shocked me most was how many stories people were writing about it), but that does not make it violent. Throwing soup on a person might be violent, but throwing soup on a painting (without doing permanent damage  no less) is not.

Comment: @Obie2.0 I meant "peacefully" here is more in the sense of "without disturbing the peace" rather than "non-violent". Perhaps not the best word to use.

Comment: @AmiralPatate In fact, the same protestors did previously blockade some oil refineries or storage depots or something like that. You can guess what happened: *absolutely nothing*. Nothing changed, nobody talked about it, they just got thrown in jail and we continued killing ourselves and the planet making without a single peep. At least the paintings made us sit up for a moment and talk about the fact we're killing ourselves and the planet.